# How to take out values from pdf - SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, pdf, sharepoint-2010

I have ceated a program to take out the metadata values from pdf using iTextSharp and iTextSharp.pdfa. I want to take a value "First Name" from the pdf please note the below details of my written program and somebody kindly help me to search vaule in pdf

object reference error is hitting in this line!!!

string abc = document.CustomValues["Your First Name:"].ToString();

If I want find the "Your First Name:" from inside the pdf, how to do this?

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinPdfSP
{
    class PdfDocuments
    {     
      static public class CompatiblePdfReader
      {
public void ExtractMetadata(string sourcePath="C:\\Users\\UserName1\\Desktop\\SampleData.pdf")
            {
                PdfDocument document = CompatiblePdfReader.Open(sourcePath);

                string abc = document.CustomValues["Your First Name:"].ToString();

                    string docdet=

                    document.Info.Author.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.CreationDate.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.Creator.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.Keywords.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.ModificationDate.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.Producer.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.Subject.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Info.Title.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.FileSize.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.FullPath.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Guid.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Language.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.PageCount.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    document.Version.ToString();

                    document.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In your PDF is "Your First Name" actually a value in the metadata or is it a value in a formfield/the layout in the PDF?

Comment: Dear thst,  Thank you very much for quick reply!!!!!

In my PDF two entries are possible like this

Your First Name: David___

Your Last Name: _____George_______

I am trying to get this value using the string argument

eg: if I input "Your First Name" I should get output as "David"

Comment: Hello thst, It is form field in the PDF not actually a value in metadata. Could you please suggest something to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your comments, the field labels ("Your First Name" and "Your Last Name") do not exist as anything other than text in the pdf ("not actually a value in metadata"). If that is the case there's probably not really a pretty way of doing it, since you don't really have any guarantee how the text is stored in the pdf.

So unless you wan't to really dig into the pdf-format, you may be out of luck. *But* you may also be lucky enough that "Your First Name: John Dough" is actually stored together as one string (as opposed to, say, 2 different objects: "Your First Name:" and separately "John Dough").

If one object, you could use any of the methods mentioned here [to extract all text from the pdf](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C). One of the solutions uses iTextSharp, which you are already using. Personally I have successfully used PDFBox (also mentioned in the link). Once converted to text, you can then look in the text and see where the names are stored relative to the field label and build a regular expression for extracting it.

For this to work, though, the input pdf's must be similar enough that the "to string" conversion results in a consistent and findable pattern regarding where the names are placed relative to the Labels. As mentioned: If you are lucky: they will be right next to each other. Less lucky: a lot of other text in between. Out of luck: text string is just the chars in the pdf in a seemingly random order.

Good luck,

/adam

Comment: @Ajain, a good way of showing that answers are helpful is by upvoting them. Also, if an answer correctly answered you question, it's nice to pick it as an answer (click check mark). best /

Answer (score 1):

If your PDF really still contains the formfields (AFAIK PDF/A disallows acrofields), you can access the formfields in the Acrofields object in itextsharp.

[Update: What version of itextsharp are you using? This code snippet is for the java itext 2.1.7 (LGPL version), but it should point you in the right direction anyway. If you have XFA fields, the itext* support is limited in some aspects. I suggest you check the code samples at Chapter 6 of the *itext in action book* http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=121]

To access a field use the following code snippet (this is Java, but itextsharp should be similar):

```
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
if( fields != null ) {
    String value = fields.getFieldItem("My Field Name").getValue(0);
    [ ... do sth with the value ... ]
}
```

Hope this gets you running. Acrofields are a beast and sometimes pretty strange to handle. As long as you talk textfields, you should be ok. For Radiobuttons or Checkboxes, you should sure look into the `AppearanceState` description in the PDF reference.

Comment: Dear thst,You are saying correct AcroFields are correct option to extract metadata key values inside the PDF, only key values can extract not all words in PDF. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ajain if you check the result of reader.AcroFields in your pdf, does it return anything? If not, or result is null, then you have no Acrofields and the only option is text extraction as proposed by AdamAL.